# Finding percentage of memory instructions in a program

Tags: memory

So i have a question as such:

```
cache access time: 5ns
penalty = 200ns
hit rate = 0.95 for instruction cache
hit rate = 0.90 for data cache
1k Instructions
Total memory access time = 23,750ns
```

Find memory instruction percentage in the program.
**My approach**

```
instructions found in cache: 950 * 5 = 4750ns
instructions not found in cache = 50*(200+5) = 10,250
Total time = 4750 + 10,250 = 15,000
Percentage = 15,000 / 23,750 = 0.63 so 63%
```

However this doesn't seem right because for a second question it asks, if data cache hit rate is improved to 95%, what is total memory access time. That would mean total access time for data cache would be same as instruction cache(because both of them are at 95% now) and thus it would be 15,000.
Total memory access time then would be = 15,000 + 15,000 = 30,000 which is more than the original access time. That doesn't make sense because if we are improving the hit rate, shouldn't the total access time go down?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for Kaushik Patra's SJSU CS147 class homework.

Total_access_time = instruction_access_time + data_access_time
instruction_access_time = (1000 * 5ns) + (0.05 * 1000 * 200ns) = 15000ns
So we get data_access_time = 8750ns, we need to figure out what percent of the memory instruction is used in the data_access_time

data_access_time = (memory_fraction * 1000 * 5ns) + (memory_fraction * 0.10 * 1000 * 200ns)
After some algebra you should get memory_fraction is 0.35